# jquery: scrollTop - scroll all divs within container div

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm probably over thinking this:

I have the following set up:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='titlebar'><p class='clickObj'>Title</p></div>
        <div id='content' style='display: none;'>...stuff</div>
    </div>

    <div id='container'>
        <div id='titlebar'><p class='clickObj'>Title</p></div>
        <div id='content' style='display: none;'>...stuff</div>
    </div>

    <div id='container'>
        <div id='titlebar'><p class='clickObj'>Title</p></div>
        <div id='content' style='display: none;'>...stuff</div>
    </div>

    <div id='container'>
        <div id='titlebar'><p class='clickObj'>Title</p></div>
        <div id='content' style='display: none;'>...stuff</div>
    </div>


</div>
```

When you click on the title in clickObj, the associated content div's slides down. I then want the parent container to slide to the top of the wrapper div, pushing or pulling the other container divs with it. Hopefully that made sense.

I looked at scrollTo but wasn't sure how to use it for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".clickObj").click(function() {
        $(window).scrollTo($(this).offset().left, $(this).offset().top);
    });
```

Somthing like this ? (using Jquery)

Comment: Maybe, but I only want it to scroll within the wrapper div. So if there are 5 container divs within wrapper and you click on container 3, then 1, 2 and 3 scroll up, with 1 and 2 being hidden and 3 stopping at top of wrapper, and 4 and 5 move up - i tried this: var offset = $("#accordionWrapper").offset();
     $(this).parents('#accordionContainer').scrollTo(offset.top); but got no results